# Passing instances of a model to a django formset

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have the following models defined:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Fixture(models.Model):
    HomeTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="HomeTeam")
    AwayTeam = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="AwayTeam")
    HomeTeamScore = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    AwayTeamScore = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateTimeField()

class Prediction(models.Model):
    Fixture = models.ForeignKey(Fixture)
    PredictHomeTeam = models.IntegerField()
    PredictAwayTeam = models.IntegerField()
    PredictionDate = models.DateTimeField()
    User = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

So if use a filter to get 6 fixtures based on Date then I would like to pass these into a formset of PredictionForm but I am struggling on how to pass in the fixture since it is required as a foreignkey field.

This is my first django project so I guess I am also looking for confirmation on whether I am on the right lines with using formsets for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [model formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) which works just like a normal [formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) but understands how to work with models.

```
from django.forms.models import modelformset_factory
PredictionFormSet = modelformset_factory(Prediction)
```

The formset documentation describes how to [use initial data with your formset](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset):

```
PredictionFormSet(initial=[{'Fixture': fixture, 'User': user}])
```

Just as a note, use lowercase and underscores for all of your class method/attributes. Instead of this:

```
Fixture = models.ForeignKey(Fixture)
```

Do this:

```
fixture = models.ForeignKey(Fixture)
```

This makes it easier to read and reason about your code for other programmers. You should read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is the official Python style guide.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I am after. Thanks for the convention tips also.